# Copy Data between SQL Databases

Tags: sql

I have 2 Databases (Database1) and (Database2)
DataBase1 has one table (table1)
DataBase2 has one table (table2)

DataBase1.table1 (id as int, code as nvarchar(20), PunhTime as datetime)
DataBase2.table2 (code2 as nvarchar(20), MyDate as datetime, Time1 as nvarchar(8) , Time2 as nvarchar(8))

could Achieve that through SQL ?

thanks in advance

here photo to show how data should copy ..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcOG0.jpg)

Comment: this is a question about pivoting really, see image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
WITH cte_PunchTime AS (
    SELECT Code, CONVERT(date, PunchTime) as MyDate, CONVERT(time, PunchTime) as [Time], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY PunchTime) AS [Rank]
    FROM DataBase1.table1
)
INSERT INTO DataBase2.table2( Code2, MyDate, Time1, Time2)
SELECT Code, MyDate, MIN([Time]) AS Time1, MAX([Time]) AS Time2 
FROM cte_PunchTime 
GROUP BY Code, MyDate
```

You can use the Rank and PIVOT to use it for more than two columns.  But number of columns need to be defined. For example, below code is for 4 columns.

```
WITH cte_Product AS (
    SELECT Code, CONVERT(date, PunchTime) as MyDate, CONVERT(time, PunchTime) as [Time]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY PunchTime) AS [Rank]
    FROM DataBase1.table1
)
INSERT INTO DataBase2.table2( Code, MyDate, Time1, Time2, Time3, Time4)
SELECT * FROM cte_Product 
PIVOT ( 
    Min([Time]) FOR [Rank] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) Result;
```

Comment: Thanks sir a lot for that, what about if have more than tow dates, like 10? I have update the photo if check please , you have use MIN and MAX that ok if have only 2 date record, what function if have 10 dates of record?

Comment: thanks a lot sir, it is work great , but last question please , when that query execute then database2 will have record, what about if query run again need to update exist record with specific date and code without adding new record , that is last point and many thanks

Comment: Add IF NOT EXISTS condition on table2.Code2 and MyDate for INSERT, ELSE update.

Comment: if please can write draft for that, please

Answer (score 0):

If they are running the databases on the same server, it is relatively easy to do:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DataBase2.table2
(
  [code2],
  [Time1]
)
SELECT [code], [PunhTime]
FROM dbo.DataBase1.table1
```

You only have to change the column, since I it is unclear which column should go to which column.

Comment: And also make sure other column are allow null.

Comment: Sorry I have Add photo to show how data to be copy from database1.table1 to database2.table2

Comment: You've to write a select query which gets the data like how you want it, and use that

Comment: Yes that is right , but how to write that sql query to get copy data as shown?